# Subset a raster using row/column index

Tags: r, gis, raster

When subsetting a matrix or DF, it is possible to reference row columns, such as `df1[1:5, 3:10]`, or `df3[2:4, ]`.

**Is there any way to do this with a raster? That is, can I clip just rows 500:700, for example from a raster object?**

I have tried using `rasterFromCells()`, but it doesn't give me the result I want (and it seems like there should be a more simple solution given R's other slick subsetting methods).

**Example:**

```
r <- raster(ncols = 50, nrow = 50)
r[] <- 1:ncell(r)

# I would like to subset the bottom 50 rows of cells, but keep it as a raster.
# However, this returns a numeric object.
rSub <- r[30:50, 1:50]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please add a minimal reproducible example!

Comment: Do you want the cell values themselves or another raster object?

Comment: My apologies; I have added a small example. I would like to keep it as a raster object.

Comment: It is not enough clear for me. With this r[30:50, 1:50]  you are subsetting the last 20 rows, right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't find the question very clear.

However, is this what you are looking for?

```
subR <- crop(r, extent(r, 30, 50, 1, 50))

plot(subR)
```

The function `crop()` of `raster` package does the trick because allow you to subset the raster object using rows and columns.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. When I originally read it in the Raster documentation, I took "extent" to refer to spatial extent. 

Sorry for the question quality. Thanks again.

Comment: I am pretty sure you can `crop` also using the spatial coordinate.

Comment: And note that `extent(r, 30, 50, 1, 50))` returns a spatial extent.

Comment: @gvan if this is the answer to your question you should validate it

Answer (score 4):

I prefer using crop as shown by Seymour. There is another way, using  `drop=FALSE`

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(ncols = 10, nrow = 10)
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)

rSub <- r[3:5, 2:3, drop=FALSE] 
rSub
#class       : RasterLayer 
#dimensions  : 3, 2, 6  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
#resolution  : 36, 18  (x, y)
#extent      : -144, -72, 0, 54  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
#source      : memory
#names       : layer 
#values      : 22, 43  (min, max)
```