# Subset a raster using row/column index in terra

Tags: r, gis, raster, terra

I'm trying, in the package terra, to subset a raster by row and column numbers.
Apparently that is easy in raster, at least without a geographic extent and crs:
[Subset a raster using row/column index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49433361/subset-a-raster-using-row-column-index).
But I can't get it to work in terra.
There has to be an easy way.  terra::subset only selects layers of a raster.

Expecting someone to ask why: I padded a raster with rows and columns before sampling an elevation raster and calculating slope and aspect, which relies on neighboring cells.  Now I need to strip off those padded rows and columns.

```
library(terra)
EXT <- c( -108, -105, 39, 42 )
R <- rast( extent=EXT, ncol=14, nrow=14, crs="epsg:4326" )
R[] <- 1:ncell(R)

# Now try to strip off the outer 2 rows and columns
crop( x=R, y=ext( 3, 12, 3, 12 ) )
# Error: [crop] extents do not overlap

# Normal R-style subsetting also does not work,
# just gives values of that subset
R[ 3:12, 3:12 ]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can subset with `drop=FALSE`

```
library(terra)
r <- rast( extent=c( -108, -105, 39, 42 ), ncol=14, nrow=14, crs="epsg:4326" )
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)

x <- r[ 4:12, 3:10, drop=FALSE]
x
#class       : SpatRaster 
#dimensions  : 9, 8, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
#resolution  : 0.2142857, 0.2142857  (x, y)
#extent      : -107.5714, -105.8571, 39.42857, 41.35714  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
#source      : memory 
#name        : lyr.1 
#min value   :    45 
#max value   :   164
```

Verify

```
xy <- xyFromCell(x, cells(x))
range(rowFromY(r, xy[,2]))
#[1]  4 12
range(colFromX(r, xy[,1]))
#[1]  3 10
```

As to the "why", I would use `crop(slope, original)` to remove the padded values. That is, the second argument of `crop` should be your original SpatRaster without the padded cells, or the SpatExtent thereof (`ext(orginal)`)